# How do we maintain polytropic processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

In polytropic processes for an ideal gas,

$$PV^{\alpha}=constant$$ where $\alpha \neq 0,1,\gamma$

And $\gamma$ is adiabatic exponent of gas

So, how these processes are maintained?

What things are done to initiate  this process?

Comment: You are asking about a reversible polytropic process that is neither isothermal, isochoric, isobaric nor adiabatic?

Comment: Yeah, exactly !

Comment: You realize there are an infinite number of possible values of $\alpha$ other than these.

Comment: Yes, I am already aware.

Comment: Check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process#Equivalence_between_the_polytropic_coefficient_and_the_ratio_of_energy_transfers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a a polytropic process is one for which $TdS=\mathcal K dT$ and $\mathcal K$ is a constant. Using the $dU=TdS-pdV$ equation it follows that
$$\frac{dp}{p}+\alpha \frac{dV}{V}=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and upon integration you get $$pV^{\alpha}=K_0\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $\alpha=\frac{C_p-K}{C_V-K}$.
This means that if you change the volume by an amount of, say, $\delta V$ then you have to change the pressure by $\delta p = -p \alpha \frac{dV}{V}$. This can be achieved by absorbing $\delta S=\frac{\mathcal K}{T}\delta T$ entropy from a thermal reservoir at temperature $T+\delta T$ where $pV=RT$ and $\delta T=({V \delta p+p \delta V})/R\alpha=\frac{1-\alpha}{R\alpha}p \delta V$

Answer (score 2):

You add or remove heat to change the temperature along the polytropic path in such a way that the exponent $\alpha$ remains constant.  You have $$d\ln{P}+\alpha d\ln{V}=0$$and $$d\ln{P}+d\ln{V}=d\ln{T}$$So $$dln{T}=(1-\alpha)d\ln{V}$$or$$TV^{\alpha-1}=const$$